# how to check if person follow another in twitter API V1.1

Tags: twitter

I know that twitter migrated to api v1.1

I previously used to check if a person follows another person or not with the following code snippet:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a=Mamdoh_Salah&screen_name_b=rno
```

**But how can I get the same result in api v1.1?**
I get my authenicate (Acess request) and it is all ok but when I check the page like this

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a=Mamdoh_Salah&screen_name_b=rno
```

I get this message:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Does anyone know if they support another link in api v1.1?

Answer (score 3):

friendships/show gives you info about the relationship between two users.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/show

Calls are limited to 180 per 15-min window.

Answer (score 1):

In the v1.1 API, they have replaced it with the [friendships/lookup API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/lookup) where you can specify a comma separated list of up to 100 users and it'll tell you about the connections between the authenticating user and each of the users specified

Comment: do you know antother wat return the relationship between any two persons not authenticating users ... i think this works if account just authenticating and another one .... but if i need to check between non authenticating

Answer (score 0):

A third technique is using the /followers/ids endpoint (5000 per call), the overlapping ids between all your friends/ids and followers/ids, will give you the ids of the accounts you're following who follow you back.